# How's This for a Simple HTTP Callout Retry Framework?

Tags: apex, callout, scheduled-apex, queueable-interface

Most of what I have read about retry operations is that they are vaguely complicated and indepth. I have written the code below which seems to accomplish this without too much confusion - I'm wondering if there are any pitfalls I am not seeing here.

The class uses a top-level schedulable class, which calls a queueable class to make the callout, and if the callout is unsuccessful, it just schedules the top level class again five minutes later. After testing it appears this works indefinitely.

A simple string token, assigned at the first invocation, is also passed between the classes, and I have tested and found that the token does persist, even when runs are scheduled for a later time.

Thanks for helpful thoughts!

```
public class SelfServe implements Schedulable {

    public String Token = null;

    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {        

        RetrieveMachineDetails Job = new RetrieveMachineDetails();
            Job.Token = Token;    
        System.enqueueJob(Job);

    }     

    public class RetrieveMachineDetails implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

        public String Token = null;

        public void execute(QueueableContext context){                              

            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();        
                    request.setEndpoint('https://app.endpoint.com/api');
                    request.setMethod('POST');
                    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');                 
                    request.setBody('{"query":  "$message_=\'METRIC\' && $tier=\'customer\' "}');                                                                                                                                                                       
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);              

            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                //do stuff     
            }

            else { //retry

                DateTime Dt = system.now().addMinutes(5);            
                   String day = string.valueOf(Dt.day());                    
                   String month = string.valueOf(Dt.month());                      
                   String hour = string.valueOf(Dt.hour());                   
                   String minute = string.valueOf(Dt.minute());                                   
                   String year = string.valueOf(Dt.year());                  
                String ScheduledTime = '0 ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ?' + ' ' + year;

                SelfServe Job = new SelfServe();
                    Job.Token = Token;
                System.schedule('SelfServe Job'+Dt, ScheduledTime, Job);

            }
        }   
    } 
}
```

Comment: First thing that jumps out is that your endpoint may be vulnerable to injection.

Comment: Protected this question to prevent a spammer from continuing to spam their blog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only downside is that this may not work for callouts that you need to make from a trigger, because of the 100 scheduled job limit (you can't have more than 100 pending jobs scheduled). A more elegant solution would store pending requests in a queue of some sort, and call itself every few minutes or so. The reason why many designs are "vaguely complicated and indepth" is because they need to accommodate a number of use cases, such as being called from a flow, trigger, on a regular basis, etc. Your design is perfectly fine if it's for some low-traffic job like a daily synchronization job or something, but would not scale well to higher frequency use cases.